# Matching columns and sorting them with 1 of them being numbers and different lengths

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 3 columns, 2 of them text and one of them numbers.

Example - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z54KZwZTO368yueK5NVgXvA2loEwHJEvSIrJ8SQ5hm0/edit?usp=sharing

the formula I tried using among others:

```
=sort(A2:C10,match(C2:C10,{"baseball";"cats";"dogs";"fish";"helmets";"bones";"funny";"sad";"bye"},1),true)
```

Any idea how I can match A with C when C also has a bunch of other rows beyond A and also A is connected with the numbers on B while C is not.

The order however must go by C based on a partial match of A.

Any suggestions with google sheets?

Comment: Can you provide an expected output? The way you defined the output you want to achieve in the post is kind of unclear (to me).

Comment: I didn't understand the use of column B. Is it just for sorting purposes? If so, would it interfere too much if you changed B for C? Because when you try to match the range as `A2:C10` you also take B column into account. As for the number of rows in C column, you can declare your range as `C2:C`, and it will consider the whole column starting from `C2`

Comment: Please show your _hand-entered_ expected results and explain why they are the correct results. Consider showing _realistic-looking_ sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `*` wildcard with `match()`:

`=sort( A2:C10, match(C2:C10, { "baseball"; "cats"; "dogs"; "fish"; "helmets"; "bones"; "funny"; "sad"; "bye" } & "*", 0), true )`